# Can I use "Have been" with "Until" in this sentence?

Tags: word-choice, tense, past-continuous

My intention is to explain that I used to be stressed and depressed but then I read an article about stress relief techniques and that helped me.

Is this sentence using "Have been" and "Until" grammatically correct? If not, what's the best way to write it?

> I have been dealing with stress, anxiety, and depression until I stumbled upon a writing on stress relief techniques involving meditation and yoga.

Comment: **until** alone isn't the key to the question.  **stumbled** is critical word.  You could use **until** with the future:  *I must keep digging this hole and filling it back up again until the warden **says** I've dug enough.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not really correct, because "have been dealing" is the [**present perfect continuous**](https://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/presentperfectcontinuous.html) (which is a *present* tense like the name says, talking about a present status!) but "until I stumbled" is talking about a past event.

More fluent would be the simple past "I **was** dealing with stress, anxiety, and depression until I stumbled upon (etc.)" or the past perfect continuous "I **had** been dealing with stress, anxiety, and depression until I stumbled upon (etc.)"  (thanks to Jasper for pointing out the past  perfect continuous!)

Comment: Changing "I have been" to "I had been" would also fix the tense problem.

Answer (score -1):

**EDIT:** I stand corrected on the verb tense. Please see @stangdon's answer and @Jasper's comment. "Have been" should be "had been" or "was".

**ORIGINAL ANSWER:** Your usage of "have been" and "until" are perfect. However "a writing" is a little unnatural, usage wise. Instead of "a writing", I would use "an article".